# dynamically create image while debugging iOs lldb

Tags: ios, objective-c, lldb

I wonder if it's possible to create UIImage and preview it while debugging ios application. I know it's possible if there's already a variable in code which is complied `UIImage *img;`and while debugging set breakpoint and do something like this in debugger `po img = [self createImage]`. 
But when there's no UIImage object in code, is it possible to create one in debugger and preview image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Use the temporary variable syntax (dollar-sign prefix) to make sure you can access your variable from LLDB:

```
(lldb) e UIImage* $image = [UIImage imageNamed:"blah.png"]
```

If you want to see the image, you can add `$image` to Xcode's watch area using "Add Expression..."

Once you've added it, click the entry for `$image` and then press the Space key to use Quick Look.

Answer (score 0):

You can define new variables in the lldb expression parser.  The convention is that any variable defined in an expression that starts with '$' will be preserved after the expression is run and made available to future expressions.  So for instance:

```
(lldb) expr NSString *$myString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: "my new string"]
(lldb) po $myString
my new string
```

The data backing the new variable exists on the heap in your program, so you can pass it to other functions in your program using the expression parser as well.